# Is there any feedback or interaction while my question is into the re-opening queue?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

I've made a [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/58190/should-i-notify-my-employer-that-i-intend-to-work-on-an-open-source-or-personal) that was put `on hold` as `off-topic`. Since then I've made some edits following the automated feedback, and I believe that the reasons for putting it on hold are not valid anymore.

While the question is still on hold, I have no feedback from the close voters, so I can't know if my edits are sufficient to get it re-opened, or if there is something more I could do.

I feel that my question might get closed for the wrong reasons, and in the meantime I can't receive any more answers. What am I supposed to do? For example:

1. Should I just wait to see whether or not it gets closed after 5 days?
2. Should I start asking in the comments section if the edits are OK and start a discussion with the close-voters ?
3. Should I take the lack of responses as a sign that it will probably get closed anyway?

I don't have any experience with the hold/edit/reopen workflow, so I'm not asking for this particular question only. I've linked it as a reference, but I'd like to have an advice that could be applied to any kind of closed questions.

Thanks

Comment: 4. Ask on meta whether the edits merit reopening and, if not, what else is needed.  You've indirectly done that by posting this, so with luck you'll get some feedback.  (You can also ask in chat.)

Comment: Oh, I've read the help section, but I didn't know this. Thanks!

Comment: +1 to "ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler)". It's one of the easiest and (usually) fastest ways of getting help with rescuing a question.

Comment: Do you want to convert this post to a topic on the edits needed to make your question on-topic, or do you want to go ahead with the more general case of "how do I check the status / speed up the reopen?"? The major problem I see with your current question and what will always prevent me from reopening a company-specific close reason is that you first sentence cites a specific clause in your contract.

Comment: No, I want to keep this question here generic. Now, about my closed question, I don;t think it's company-specific either. The sentence you are talking about is a very common/generic term used in many types of contracts. I didn't even copy from my contract, I found a 95% similar one from the internet.

Comment: By the way I've made a separate specific re-opening request for my question at http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3416/reopen-should-i-notify-my-employer-that-i-intend-to-work-on-an-open-source-or-p